# When is a bounded linear operator similar to the unilateral shift?

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

I wonder if it is possible to characterize the bounded linear operators on some Hilbert space which are similar to the unilateral shift. I would like to have necessary and sufficient conditions on the operator which can be directly checked. Here are some necessary conditions on $T\in L(\mathcal H)$:

(a) $T^{*n}f\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for each $f\in\mathcal H$.

(b) For each $z\in\mathbb D$ (open disk) $T-z$ is Fredholm, injective, and $\dim\ker(T^*-\overline z) = 1$.

(c) $\|(T-z)^{-1}\|$ grows linearly to $\mathbb T = \{z : |z|=1\}$ from outside $\overline{\mathbb D}$.

(d) $\mathbb T = \sigma_c(T)$ (continuous spectrum).

However, I don't know whether these are sufficient. Does anyone know more?

Comment: @Philip I am very much interested in the problem. Can you tell me about your third necessary condition in more details. What is the exact meaning of this condition. There are plenty of example of operator satisfying your first, second and fourth condition and still it is not similar to shift.